# PHP Regex Not Quite Working

Tags: php, regex, price

I am using the following regex:

```
^[0-9.,]*(([.,][-])|([.,][0-9]{2}))?\$
```

I use this regex to check for valid prices -- so it catches/rejects things like `xxx`, or `llddd` or `34.23dsds`
and allows things like `100` or `120.00`
The problem with it seems to be if it is blank(empty) it passes as valid which it should not -- any ideas how to change this??

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't match 120.00 - https://regex101.com/r/eW3sX3/2

Comment: @splash58 you're escaping the terminating $ which (I guess is) an artefact from copy-pasting code.

Comment: This will match `,.98` which makes no sense

Comment: I suggest you look into http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php for a built-in method of parsing currency which respects locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your problems is that you use the dot in your regex which stands for "any character". If you mean a dot you need to escape it like this `\.`

Also you should have at least one number in it so exchange the asterisk `*` by a `+` for "one or more".

Then you can have .,.,.,.,.,.,- if you do not remove the comma and dot from the first part:

```
^[0-9]+(([\.,][-])|([\.,][0-9]{2}))?$
```

Comment: ok you were right wills version allowed ,, which is wrong -- your one seems to work better cheers

Comment: actually in PCRE a `.` inside `[]` is not a special character and matches "."

Comment: The reason this one works better and doesn't match ",," is because the original regex starts with `[0-9,.]` which both of us fixed in our answers

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I was not aware of the fact that in `[]` a `.` is taken literally. Makes sense though. Something learned again :-)

Answer (score 1):

Taking yoiur regex and just solving the "don't match blanks" problem:

```
^[0-9.,]+(([.,][-])|([.,][0-9]{2}))?$
```

the `*` allows 0 or more, while the `+` allows 1 or more, thus the `*` allowed blanks but the `+` will not, instead there must be at least one digit.

EDIT:

You should clean this regex up a bit to be

`^[0-9]+(?:[.,-](?:[0-9]{2})?)?$`

This solves the matching of ",,,"

http://www.regextester.com/?fam=95185

EDIT 2: [@Fuzzzzel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4306246/fuzzzzel) pointed out that this did not match the case "50,-" which we assume you would like to match and that removing capturing groups is presumptive. Here's the latest iteration of my suggested regex:

```
^[0-9]+([.,-](-|([0-9]{2}))?)?$
```

Comment: Now it matches one or more commas without digits - https://regex101.com/r/eW3sX3/3

Comment: That was part of the OP's original regex, which my second regex eliminates

Comment: To be fair, the "minus" obviously has been there to present something like 50,- but your cleaned up regex will not match that any more. And, because I am interested, why does the regex need "non-capturing group" `?:` ?

Comment: oh, I've never encountered "50,-" so that was not obvious to me. I used non-capturing groups because why would those be capturing groups?